# Can i fit an image to it's container using CSS if this container does not have any explicit width or height?

Tags: css, css-selectors

i cant fit an image to it's container that has implicit width and height

I am trying to fit an image to it's container using CSS, but the problem is that container does not have any explicit width or height.

I tried to use object-fit CSS property but did not solve the problem

Comment: Can you provide a code snippet with an example of its current state?

Comment: Need more informations!

Comment: As far i understood If you explicitly do not provide any height or width to your container by default implicitly container will be of content-height which in your case is ```img```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**So by default you cannot fill the image inside of the div since the div doesn't have a fixed width or height.** This means that the div will automatically take the image's width & height.

If you could set the height though this is how I would do it:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/21309d2e0e611c5d347f2c0beb54b168?s=64&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1" class="image"/>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container{
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 512px;
}

.image{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/equ6g7y4/24/